automatic indentation is not working in jupyter notebook . how to fix this?
actual indentation of the code is this
def function:
    print('hello world')

this is my indentation working condition in my jupyter notebook .i want to how to fix # indentation in python but also tab(4 spaces) is not working
def function:
print('hello world')


Please read and revise your post based on How do I ask a good question?. (And use that for any future posts as well.) You may wish to search and look at related questions and answers that good scores and helpful solutions. Then contrast those with your post. I suspect the high-scoring posts include detailed information on where type of machine with what type of install of which specific versons of the software is involved. Except for you tag, we aren't even informed what language is involved here. Since this is a behavior issue ....

 it could probably use support from some good illustrative screenshots. Normally these are frowned on; however, along with a good description, some screenshots can often also help give insight into something that is an active event that is opposite what is expected, presumably. ... Did this behavior start recently after your experience had been good in the past?

Did you try with def function(): as the first line? Maybe otherwise you are hitting this code mirror issue described here and at references therein?
